# How can I hide chat history from my Gmail inbox?

Tags: gmail

Gmail's [new interface for chat history](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/05/new-interface-for-gmail-chat-history.html) has apparently also had the side effect of showing chat logs as items in my inbox. I don't want this (I can look in the *Chats* label for those, thank you very much).

Can I prevent chats from appearing in my inbox? Adding the following subject logic to a filter (which is how I used to prevent them from appearing) no longer seems to work, as chat history items no longer appear to have a "subject" field at all:

```
-"Chat with"
```

Is there any other way I can prevent chat logs from appearing in my Inbox?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I figured out how to get a filter to keep chat logs from appearing in the inbox. Create a filter with the following logic in the "Has the words" section:

```
is:chats
```

Anything matching this filter should "Skip the inbox" as its action. Problem solved!

Comment: Well done, sir. Care to explain how you found that out? It's been bugging me for some time!

Comment: If you type `is:` in the search box on the Gmail page, you'll see some auto-completed choices (one of which is 'chats'). I played around with that search trick to get the right logic. I believe that `is:chat` (singular) will also work, but I use plural because that's what they suggest.

Comment: Similarly, if you want to remove chats when you're looking at "All Mail", just plug "-is:chats" (sans quotes) into the search box. That will show you all mail but not chat histories.

Thanks for this tip, it helped me figure out what I needed to exclude chat histories when I was trying to look through "All Mail"!